# Angular2 Call javascript API when router changes page

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have an Angular2 component that has a template which requires a JavaScript calls to load it's html component, Ex. Facebook, Google Maps and some custom scripts.

The scripts are already loaded in the index.html and i just need to call them to update it's contents.

How do i call my javascript methods in angular2 when the view is changed again.

Code Example;

myJavaScript.js

```
loadData(){
...
}
$(document).load(loadData());
```

now i want to call my loadData() everytime the router views my component again.

Comment: Did you tried using ngOnInit() function for the same.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal but how do i use my javascript method inside it? the compiler won't allow it.

Comment: On top of ya file try declare function foo();///js function. I assume your js function is available as global object.  Now call that function foo in in ngOnInit()

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal please put that as an answer so i can select it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of your file 
`declare function foo();///js function`
It assume your js function is available as global object. 
Now call that function foo in in `ngOnInit()` lifecycle of your component